# IE onpaste JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, paste

No matter what I do, I can't get IE to select() the value in a  after a "paste" event in canceled.

Look at this URL in IE, and paste anything into the textarea:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfApa/1/

The text should be selected after pasting. This works in Chrome, but can't figure out how to get select() to work when i'm canceling the paste even in IE:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').on('paste', function(e) {
    this.value = 'fooo';
    setTimeout(function(){ $(e.target).select(); }, 0);

    return false; 
});
```

Don't ask me why it works, I just got curious and found a solution.

It seems that selecting just doesn't work in the context of the paste event handler, maybe there's something that happens afterwards in the browser that deselects (though `preventDefault` still didn't help)

Comment: Man, this is scary, and you're a genious. I was having a problem with the `paste` event and IE, and wrapping the whole code in a `setTimeout(function(){ /mycodehere/ }, 0);` did the trick. O_O

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://webcloud.se/log/Selecting-text-with-JavaScript/.
I think that's the issue, and you can make a workaround by using

```
var range = this.createTextRange();
range.moveStart("character",0);
range.moveEnd("character",$(this).html().length);
range.select();
```

Comment: Thanks, but tried very similar code and didn't have any success. Implemented your answer though (unfortunately, it doesn't work) at http://jsfiddle.net/xesQe/2/. No matter what you do in 'paste' in IE, there seems to be some mysterious event that fires afterward and clears out the selection.

Comment: Sorry. Glad to know ori's workaround worked out. Got to be some glitch in IE for now, which the timeout with a callback fixes. You can put the -1 back if you want, I didn't mean to be spiteful about it.