# jQuery or plain JS: execute function after event listener returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

Let's say I have an event named "`bar`" on element `#foo`.

Is there a way I can use jQuery deferred objects to force a function to execute immediately after the `bar` event listener(s) has/have executed (returned), whether or not any `bar` listeners cancel the event?

Or maybe I don't even need jQuery for this?

EDIT: Just to clarify, triggering another event or function from within the `bar` handler is not what I'm looking for—the `bar` handler hasn't returned yet, so that's not "after that `bar` event." This question may seem odd and not make sense because I'm trying to address a very specific issue/bug in IE 8.

Something like this is needed:

```
$('#foo').afterEvent('bar').then(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I find your question interesting in itself, but if your underlying goal is addressing an IE8 issue you should post a question about that issue because there may be some other way of dealing with it.

Comment: Already have. Only one answer actually worked, but it relied on setTimeout() and wasn't deterministic.

Comment: @user979672 - Can you provide details about the issue in IE8?

Comment: Sure! I'm not trying to be difficult, I promise! The issue is that IE fires some event after `paste`, no matter the return value of `paste`. I've attached to every event in MSFT's IE API for a `textarea`, and nothing I attach to fires. In other words, there's an event that's that IE fires after `paste`, but IE *doesn't expose it* to let me cancel it. Here's the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995440/ie-onpaste-javascript-event

Comment: Are you sure it's not deterministic? A 1ms `setTimeout` did the trick for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cfApa/27/ The use of a 1ms timeout is quite common to get around some synchronization issues. And whenever it works, it works deterministically.

Comment: Change you question to reference the IE 8 issues specifically that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Just run another method within the bar event

Example

```
$('#foo').bind('bar', function () {
    // do bar stuff
    // run another method
    baz();
    // or trigger any other listening events
    $('#bin').trigger('otherEvent');
});
```

Comment: But when there are multiple bindings on the same event they are called in the order they are bound, so if one of the first ones calls `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` the later handlers don't get called at all. Isn't that what the question is asking about?

Comment: True. The question is difficult to interpret if that is a problem or not. The question seems to me that he wants to run an event and call antoher function

Comment: Correct, nnnnnn, the event needs to fire whether or not the event is canceled by any listeners. This sounds very strange and hacky, but I'm trying to address a bug in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is called multicasting delegates, where you assign multiple, and independent, handlers to the same event. It can be written in JavaScript as follows:

```
    function multicast(){
if (arguments == null || arguments.length == 0) return function(){ };

var fns = [], j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
if (typeof(arguments[i]) == "function")
fns[j++] = arguments[i];
}

return function(){
for (var i = 0; i < fns.length; i++)
fns[i]();
};
}
```

Then invoked as: *(where foo and bar are both functions)*

```
window.onload = multicast(window.onload, foo, bar);
```

no JQuery is necessary this is strictly JavaScript. You will notice that each of the functions will be executed sequentially, but independent of the return value (if any) of a previous function call.

You will find a more complete description of this at [Delphic Sage](http://www.delphicsage.com/home/blog.aspx/d=980/title=Experiments_in_Javascript_Multicast_Delegate). I would also note that the author of the linked article credits John Resig's tutorial *[Learning Advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)*

[EDIT]
I guess there is something missing from your question. The way I read it this should do what you are asking:(using function multicast() above)

```
$(#'foo').bind('bar',multicast(firstFunction, secondFunction);
```

Now, when 'bar' happens  firstFunction will execute followed immediately by secondFunction, and will do so regardless of whether the firstFunction 'cancels the event'

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as the other solutions. `bar` executes *within* the handler/listener for `window.onload`, because `window.onload` because a function that executes `window.onload`, `foo`, then `bar`, before returning from the handler.