# Pasting instead of typing text into input field with character limit javascript

Tags: javascript, character, limit, paste

I have code that limits number of characters with a sort of "countdown" field that works in real-time as the user types.

Everything works perfectly except when the user "pastes" their text.  Only when they click in the field again does it reset and know there are too many characters entered.

Is there a way to make it work on mouseup / out... or interact with a paste by user?

Here is the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
else
cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
</script>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995440/ie-onpaste-javascript-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `maxlength` property:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: This is the most basic of html and I somehow missed it.  I thought the javascript would do all the work but you're saying maxlength is a good standard to start with which limits the paste?  I see that it's working and a bit frustrated that it was such an easy fix!!!  haha.  Thank you!!

Comment: Note that this is only for `<input>` element. The `<textarea>` element added the maxlength attribute in HTML5 and is still a bit quirky in browsers (IE doesn't support it, Chrome gets confused with newlines).